# can not repost data with ajax which dynamically generated

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I am going to make a searchbox like facebook for profile search in codeigniter. I can receive profiles from my database. By clicking this profiles I want to go to that profile. I want to do it without using query string! I want to send ajax request again when user click on any profile and receive info for that user from database and show it my view ! The problem is I can not post clicked data to server with ajax my code is here please help me and suggest me right approach to do this task with codeigniter.

Controller:

```
class Search_profile_controller extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();        
        $this->load->model('search_profile_model');

    }

    public function index(){      
        session_start();        
        $user = $_SESSION['username'];
        $search_query = $this->input->post('searchword');            
        $data = $this->search_profile_model->search_profile($search_query);    
        foreach ($data as $row)
        {
            $username = $row->username;
            $avtar = $row->avatar;         
            echo '<div class="display_box" id = "search_result"  align="left">';       
           if(is_null($avtar))
           {
               echo '<img src = "http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/user/no-image.jpg" width="20px" height="20px"/>'.str_repeat('&nbsp;',3); echo'<a href="">'.  $username.'</a>' ;                        
           }else         
           { 
               echo '<img src="'.$avtar.'" width="20px" height="20px"/>'.str_repeat('& nbsp;',3); echo'<a href="">'. $username.'</a>' ;
           }
           echo '</div>';
        }      
    }
}
```

My jQuery code is here

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    if($("#display1").on("click","a",(function(){
        var search_result =  $(this).html();
        var clicked_profile = 'result=' + search_result; 
        alert(clicked_profile);             
        $.ajax({           
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://localhost:1337/PhpProject1/search_profile_controller/",
            data:clicked_profile,
            success:function(html){                
                $("#pro_clicked").html(html);
            },
            error:function(err){  
                alert("This is error");                
            }         
      })                   
   })));
})
```

my HTML:

```
<div id="display1" style="position:absolute"></div>   
<div id="pro_clicked"></div>
```

Comment: Why do you have your event handler inside a if statement?

Comment: what you get in html.? `console.log(html);`

Comment: I getting profile list in display1 and every profile is under diplay_box which is dynamically generated ! you can see it in my controller

Comment: "The problem is I can not post clicked data to server with ajax " <-- Why not? Does a magical fairy appear every time you code that? Does an error pop up? Does seemingly nothing happen? Also: Please format your code properly. Add whitespace so that it is indented properly, which helps a lot when someone else tries to read your code.

Comment: I am doing it like this http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html

Comment: I can get user profile name in var clicked_profile but in ajax an error function fires everytime and give me object object error

Comment: I am surprised !! there is no error in chrome and in mozilla its not working and throws error ! and in inspect element console its showing this error - uncaught exception: out of memory

Answer (score 0):

I think there is the problem is with event delegation,

Change

```
$("#display1").on("click","a",(function(){
```

to

```
$(document).on("click","#display1 a",(function(){
```